# How to save input in yii to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I have this code Im trying to save the content and the title from a form I made..It has an id that autoincrement the id number adds in the database but the title and the content isn't/cant be save in the database. Can you please check my code if I've done something wrong? or what I'm lacking at.

Here is my model ContentForm.php

```
<?php
class ContentForm extends CActiveRecord{
public $content;
public $title;

public function tableName(){
    return 'tbl_content';
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'contentid' => 'contentid',
        'content' => 'content',
        'title' => 'title',
        // 'email' => 'Email',
        // 'usrtype' => 'Usrtype',
    );
}
```

Here is my view content.php

```
<div>
<p>User: <a href="viewuserpost">
<?php 
echo Yii::app()->session['nameuser']; 
 ?>
 </a>
 </p>
 </div>
 <h1>Content</h1>

 <?php
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'contact-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
));
?>

 Title:
 <div class="row">
 <?php
echo $form->textfield($model,'title');
 ?>

 </div>
 </br>
 Body:
 <div class="row">
 <?php 
echo $form->textArea($model,'content',array('rows'=>16,'cols'=>110));
 ?>
 </div>

 <div class="row buttons">

 <?php 
echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord? 'Create':'Save'); 
 ?>

 </div>

 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

and here is my content action in my sitecontroller.php

```
public function actionContent(){

    $model=new ContentForm;

        if(isset($_POST['ContentForm'])) {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['ContentForm'];
            if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('content','contentid'=>$model->contentid));
            $this->redirect(array('content','title'=>$model->title));
            $this->redirect(array('content','content'=>$model->content));

            }

    $this->render('content',array('model'=>$model));        

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may missed rules , add this in your model ContentForm.php

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
       array('content,title', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

For  more about model validation

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation/

Comment: There was an error I combine the content and the title inside the (' ') in the: array('content , title', 'safe') and it worked


Thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
public $content;
public $title;
```

from your class.

Yii uses PHP magic methods. And when you add attributes to your class, PHP doesn't call them but references to your explicitly written attributes.

Moreover, you should add some validation, if you use `$model->attributes=$_POST['ContentForm'];`. Another variant is to use unsecure `$model->setAttributes($_POST[ContentForm], false)` where false tells Yii to set all attributes, not only that are considered safe.

Note, that `attributes` is not real Model attribute, this is virtual attribute accessed through magic methods.

Also, you don't need three redirects. This is HTTP redirect to other page. This time, you just should just specify route to model view action and its parameter that is id, for example. Like this `$this->redirect(array('content/view','id'=>$model->contentid));`.

Of course, simplest way for you is to create new model and controller with actions using Gii.

Comment: I didn't try your answer because it already worked (ramamoorthy_villi's answer) but I'll keep that in mind..thanks ^_^